# Forcing size of a complex Flash object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

As I've found recently, setting `width`/`height` properties on a `Sprite` only forces the `Sprite` to fit the given dimensions by scaling the *actual* size, which is calculated by Flash based on the rendered content.

This leaves me confused. If I have a custom `Sprite` subclass which draws using `Graphics`, how can I do layout before an initial render - the size will be zero until it is first drawn?

For a more complex issue, let's say I have a 2D game world with objects spread over a wide area with world coordinates from (0,0) to (5000,5000), where each object has a size of maybe up to 100x100.
I want to have a Flash component which is the "game window", and has a fixed size like 400x300, rendering part of the game world. So how do I force the game window size to 400x300 pixels? I can draw a 400x300 rectangle to get the size correct but then if I draw any objects which are partly in-view, they can screw this up.

Is the right approach to provide a custom `setSize(w,h)` method which is used rather than `width` & `height` setters? But even so, is there no way to make a `Sprite` *force* to the size I want? Do you really have to catch it every render and re-scale it?

Comment: You can just draw transparent (or background colored) rectangle on sprite, it will give it size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your game world is a child object of your window, and its size is always 5000x5000, but you need `width` and `height` of the window to refer only to the window itself?  Use a mask, as the other comment suggests, then override the `width` and `height` getters and setters:

```
private var _width: Number = 400;
private var _height : Number = 300;
private var _mask : Sprite;

// some code in between

override public function get width () : Number {
    return _width;
}

override public function get height () : Number {
    return _height;
}

override public function set width ( wid:Number ) : void {
    _width = wid;
    if(_mask != null) _mask.width = wid;
}

override public function set height ( hei : Number ) : void {
    _height = hei;
    if (_mask != null) _mask.height = hei;
}
```

Comment: Essentially, yes. This is only an example, to illustrate my fixed 400x300 'window'. Is overriding `width`/`height` considered good practice? I thought of it but was concerned it might be wrong somehow.

Comment: Its good practice as long as its method works in the same manor as the original method you're overriding. Having surprising results from a standard method could be frustrating to you and confusing to other developers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you need to also need to override scaleX and scaleY to lock them to 1.0?

Comment: To prevent access to the property - yes.  I don't see why this would be necessary in your own code, though.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it in my opinion is to use a mask. You have one game container where all game DisplayObjects are added to, and on top of that container you'd have a nice user interface around the game container with a mask in the center. That way the game container will only be drawn within the boundary of the mask.

Comment: Any links? I've not come across masks before.

Comment: Via the IDE: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/drawing/creating_masks/creating_masks02.html

Via AS3 code:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/

Answer (score 0):

Another option to force a size is to create new Sprites inside the thing you want to have width/height, placing them at the four corners.  It is simple to do this with code, or via the authoring environment.